# Django pages with similar structure but different components

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a main webpage that displays and lists all the fruits (with description, price, etc) I sell.

Now, I would like to have another page .../discount which displays and list all the fruits which are True for is_discount in one of my models.

Essentially, the .../discount page is just a subset of the main page. They have the same page structure and everything, except the listings in .../discount page are discounted fruit items, whereas the mainpage can have discounted and non-discounted fruit items.

How would I go about tackling this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use the same template, and have two views: one with normal items, and one with discounted ones.

This could be done trivially with two `ListView` class views. Set the template as the same on each, then implement a `get_queryset` method on each class. In one class, have it return the full list of items (paginated or whatever), and in the method on the other class, return a queryset that's been filtered to only return discounted items. If you need other differences (like a different title on each), implement `get_context_data` as well, and return a context that contains the differences, then plug them in in the template.

---

This could be done with function views or simple `View` subclasses as well, but a `ListView` handles a lot of the boilerplate for you.